# Angularjs with bootstrap ui-datepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angularjs-bootstrap

How to control datepicker object to call open/close method of datepicker.
how to get datepicker object in another angularjs directive.

** HTML **

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="popup1.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" picker-date />
```

**Directive:**

```
   module.directive('pickerDate', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        priority: 1,
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
          console.log(ctrl)
          element.on('click', function() {                
          });
          // console.log();
        }
      };
    });
```

When element click, how to call a method of datepicker?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How can call datepicker's method in scope object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the html, you have `is-open="popup1.opened"`.
So you can control this by changing the boolean value of `$scope.popup1.opened`.

```
$scope.popup1.opened = true; // open date picker
$scope.popup1.opened = false; // close date picker
```

If you want to change this when an element is clicked, you can use [`ng-click`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick).
For **example**:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="popup1.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" picker-date />
<button type="button" ng-click="popup1.opened = !popup1.opened"></button>
```

Comment: sorry but can't call a method of datepicker in `link` function?
because i am going to get datepicker's datetime.